# Moving points 5 feet "downstream" along polyline using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, field-calculator, point

I've got a bunch of points that currently sit at the origins of a bunch of different lines. I need to move every single point 5 feet "downstream". I'm using ArcMap without an advanced license so I can't use Generate Near Table or anything in the Proximity toolbox, which seems like it would be helpful.

I'm new to Linear Referencing but it seems like something using Transform Route Events might be what I'm after?

I'd also really like to write a python script to accomplish this for a large number of points, but I'm just stuck on where to start.

Comment: When you say your points sit at the origins of the lines are you saying your points always sit at the start vertex of the line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a **copy** of your lines, open table, select field Shape and type this in a field calculator:

```
!Shape!.segmentAlongLine (0, 5)
```

using Python as parser. This will create a **5m** long versions of your lines:

[image]

Add geometry attributes to these lines - "LINE_START_MID_END" and use spatial join between your points and short segments. Run this on a field Shape of resulting points:

```
arcpy.Point( !END_X!, !END_Y!)
```

which will move them 5 m down the line.

I always store intermediate results in_memory workspace, so clone your lines into it. No need in editing session when you do calculations on shape.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This is brilliant, and I believe it's exactly what I need. But I'm stumbling over using the field calculator on the Shape field, which is geometry type. I'm getting the error "Unable to update area or length field in response to shape update". I wonder what I'm missing

Comment: It means your lines stored in gdb, do one of : a) start editing them or b)copy them to shapefile or c) copy to in_memory space. Use Copy not export to

Comment: This approach makes 1 assumption, the line is longer than 5 feet.

Comment: @Hornbydd This is correct. It will place point on the end of shorter lines. I also hoping that he works in archaic units, otherwise it will end up with shorter lines.

Comment: That's interesting, I decided to do the whole thing in a Python script to try and avoid the field calculator issue and it worked, but now I'm realizing that may be because I made a backup copy of the shapefile to practice the script on. Everything came out exactly as I intended and this workflow was invaluable to me, thanks again