How to generate points along a line beginning at a random distance from the endpoint in ArcGIS Pro
I am working on a scientific survey that requires a specific number of transect points to be generated along shorelines (polylines).  I have a featureclass with the entirety of an area's shoreline broken down into individual features for each sample area.
I need to generate points along the line at fixed intervals (i.e every 2.1km for one feature, every 1.95km for another), but I also need to have the points begin at a randomly generated distance along the line, not just at the start (or 2.1km from the start).
Is there a way to generate/use a random offset when using Generate Points Along Lines?

This is a pretty basic SearchCursor inside an InsertCursor layer filter task.

Not much arcpy needed . Populate new field with random number and shorten your lines https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/396363/moving-points-5-feet-downstream-along-polyline-using-arcpy#396397

Yes, you can do this elegantly using shape Geometry Objects. Add the step size as an attribute. Then create a geometry object and copy the Featureclass into a list of objects. When you extract geometry objects they have no attributes so you could select features for each width before extracting, like I did for length in the sample. Iterate through and use the measure properties to find the point locations from measures along the line. Measures default to distance.
You iterate over the list of line geometry objects and get the length and
calculate a random start and subsequent steps. This can be inserted into a point featureclass.
I would avoid nesting arcpy Cursors, they will be slow, can only have 3 open, will clash with file locks. This method extracting geometry is much faster.
https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/classes/polyline.htm
# coastline_mark.py
# demo markers
# input <coastline> polyline
# output <coastline>_mark point
# assumes projected lines metres
# with attribute interval metres eg 1900, 2500
# random start to interval, less than interval
# rounded to integer metres
# Kim Ollivier 12 July 2024
# Creative Commons 4.0 NZ
import sys
import arcpy
import random
import math
import os

try:
    coast = sys.argv[1]
    interval = sys.argv[2]
except IndexError:
    coast_fc = 'E:/project/MyProject1.gdb/coastline'
    interval = 2500

# open a new featureclass
gdb = os.path.dirname(coast_fc)
arcpy.env.workspace = gdb
coast = os.path.basename(coast_fc)
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(gdb,
     coast + '_mark','POINT',spatial_reference = coast)
arcpy.management.AddField(coast + '_mark','id','INTEGER')

# get out the features as a geometry list that are more than 10 km
# (for my sample coastline)
arcpy.management.MakeFeatureLayer(coast,'coast_lyr','km > 10.0')
geom = arcpy.management.CopyFeatures('coast_lyr', arcpy.Geometry())
print("geometry lines count",len(geom))

id = 0
with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(coast + '_mark',['id','SHAPE@']) as cur:
    for pline in geom: 
        chain = {}
        # print(pline,type(pline))
        full_length = int(pline.length)
        id+=1
        start_length = random.randrange(0, interval)
        steps = full_length // interval
        # print("settings", full_length, start_length, steps)
        for mark in range(steps+1):
            chain[mark] = mark*interval + start_length
            pt_geom = pline.positionAlongLine(chain[mark])
            cur.insertRow([id,pt_geom])
            # print(mark,chain[mark], pt_geom.firstPoint.X,      pt_geom.firstPoint.Y)
        remainder = full_length - chain[steps]
        # print('check',full_length, steps, chain[steps], remainder, full_length - chain[steps] - remainder, (remainder < interval))
        
del cur



He wants variable step along different lines, I guess some values stored in the table

I saw that, it can be done with a little more code, but it was complicated enough and it was late. If he wants to use it I could add that in but I have had no response.

Wow, that is great @KimO, very much appreciated. I would ideally like it to have the variable start points based on a value in the attribute table, but this is an awesome start.
